# Android screenshot2 Tool NullPointerException on Linux

Tags: java, android, shell, command-line, nullpointerexception

I am using:

Java Version: 7

SDK Tools, Revision 24.4.1 (October 2015)

Taking a screenshot with the tool screenshot2 raise a NullPointerException on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and Kali Linux 2.0. It works on Mac OS X 10.11.

Command:

`$ screenshot2 -e image.png`

(Error happens even with the -s argument or without)

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.wakeup(MonitorThread.java:580)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.quit(MonitorThread.java:588)
at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.terminate(AndroidDebugBridge.java:235)
at com.android.screenshot.Screenshot.main(Screenshot.java:198)
```

Is there a fix or does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that avoid using the screenshot2 tool.

Dependencies for Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev
```

Maybe it works even without on your machine but I don't thing so.

Then you need the python package **pillow** version **2.9.0**

Dependency for Mac AND Linux:

```
sudo pip install pillow==2.9.0
```

I made this really basic script that create the screenshot image.

File screenshot.py

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import sys

binary = sys.stdin.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
stream = StringIO(binary)
image = Image.open(stream)
image.save(sys.argv[1], 'PNG')
```

Now you can use the command line to simply get a screenshot from the device like I tried above.

Example:

```
adb shell screencap -p | python screenshot.py image.png
```

Or with the -s argument for a specific device

```
adb shell -s emulator-5558 screencap -p | python screenshot.py image.png
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to mess with python for a simple screenshot, here is a bash one-liner, without any extra dependencies:

`adb exec-out screencap -p >YOUR_FILE.png`

You can also make it a bash script for daily use.